# Jqueryui draggable, how to get handle id from drag function

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Have this simple code:

```
$( "#draggable" ).draggable({ 
    handle: ".dragableHandler", 
    drag: function(e, ui) {}
});
```

and have 4 images with the class .dragableHandler, and different id each.
How inside drag function find the current handle (one of images) id?
i can only find the dragable elment info..

Answer (score 1):

You can access it via the `srcElement` of the event:

```
drag: function(e, ui) {
    var id = e.srcElement.id;
    // do what you need...
}
```

Comment: var id = $(this).attr('id');
will give me dragable element id and i need handle image id

Comment: Aren't the images the draggable elements?

Comment: thanks Wookain, however this doesn't work for me. alert(e.srcElement) gives me undefine

Answer (score 1):

ok, i've found how to find the handle elment id from inside dragable functions (like stop, drag, start).
you must use:

```
$( "#draggable" ).draggable({ 
    handle: ".dragableHandler", 
    start: function(e, ui) {
       alert(e.originalEvent.target.id);
    }
});
```